# Visual Studio 2017 Install Error at Microsoft.ClickOnce.BootStrapper.Msi

Tags: visual-studio-2017

VS 2017 Setup is throwing error at Microsoft.ClickOnce.BootStrapper.Msi. Below is the log file contents :

Something went wrong with the install.

You can troubleshoot the package failures by:

```
1. Search for solutions using the search URL below for each package failure
2. Modify your selections for the affected workloads or components and then retry the installation
3. Remove the product from your machine and then install again
```

If the issue has already been reported on the Developer Community, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, we encourage you to create a new issue so that other developers will be able to find solutions or workarounds. You can create a new issue from within the Visual Studio Installer in the upper-right hand corner using the "Provide feedback" button.

================================================================================

Package 'Microsoft.ClickOnce.BootStrapper.Msi,version=15.0.26621.2' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.ClickOnce.BootStrapper.Msi;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1335
    Details
        MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.ClickOnce.BootStrapper.Msi,version=15.0.26621.2\Microsoft.ClickOnce.BootStrapper.Msi.msi, Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1  MSIFASTINSTALL="7"  VSEXTUI="1" 
        Return code: 1335
        Return code details: The cabinet file 'cab1.cab' required for this installation is corrupt and cannot be used. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.
    Log
        C:\Users\Abhilash\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170926021659_255_Microsoft.ClickOnce.BootStrapper.Msi.log
    Impacted workloads
        .NET Core cross-platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools,version=15.0.26720.2)
        .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.0.26606.0)
        ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26724.1)
        Azure development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure,version=15.0.26711.1)
        Data storage and processing (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Data,version=15.0.26621.2)
        Universal Windows Platform development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.0.26720.2)
    Impacted components
        .NET desktop development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26621.2)
        ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26606.0)
        ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web,version=15.0.26606.0)
        Azure Cloud Services core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Azure Cloud Services tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.CloudServices,version=15.0.26504.0)
        Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics Tools (Microsoft.Component.Azure.DataLake.Tools,version=15.0.26730.0)
        Azure development prerequisites (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.Prerequisites,version=15.0.26711.1)
        Azure Resource Manager core tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.26504.0)
        Azure Resource Manager tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.26711.1)
        ClickOnce Publishing (Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Cloud Explorer (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CloudExplorer,version=15.0.26711.1)
        Data sources for SQL Server support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,version=15.0.26621.2)
        Managed Desktop Workload Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.0.26419.1)
        Microsoft Azure WebJobs Tools (Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.AzureFunctions,version=15.0.26720.2)
        Microsoft Azure WebJobs Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.AzureFunctions,version=15.0.26720.2)
        Redgate ReadyRoll Core (Component.Redgate.ReadyRoll,version=1.14.2.3918)
        Redgate SQL Prompt Core (Component.Redgate.SQLPrompt.VsPackage,version=8.0.2.1513)
        Redgate SQL Search (Component.Redgate.SQLSearch.VSExtension,version=2.4.2.1439)
        SQL Server Data Tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Universal Windows Platform tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.0.26621.2)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Cordova (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Cordova,version=15.0.26711.1)
        Universal Windows Platform tools for Xamarin (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin,version=15.0.26606.0)

I am trying to install on Windows 10 64 bit running on VMWare from a Mac.

Has anybody encountered this issue? If so how did you resolve it?

Thanks in Advance